# CloudWatch metric filter - find appearance of terms in order

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm using CloudWatch metric filters. I have a JSON log which looks like this:

```
log.info("Null message generated for request: {}", request)
```

I'm attempting to create a metric filter for this particular JSON log. I initially tried the following pattern:

```
"Null message generated for request"
```

But then, the logs metric filter attempts to see if there are individual occurrences of these terms in the JSON log. For example, I had a log statement like:

```json
{
    "timeMillis": 1609952498430,
    "thread": "main",
    "level": "INFO",
    "loggerName": "com.ewr.behvr.api.ProcessEventApi",
    "message": "The result generated markup: MarkupMessage{ \"messageTitle\" : \"Null event\", \"text\": \"Request resulted in a Null message\"}",
    "threadId": 1,
    "threadPriority": 5
}
```

Unfortunately, the filter matches this message as well, which is not supposed to be the case.

I tried using the `$.` symbol with JSON log events, but I can only do equality checks and cannot compare strings with that.

Any idea on how I can get this metric filter to work? and not have false positives?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you doing this in the AWS console, or via an SDK or CLI tool? Are you passing the double quotes, escaped, as part of the search string?

Comment: I'm doing this in the AWS console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimentation and reading through the docs once again, I was able to come up with a filter expression that looked like this:

```
{($.loggerName="com.ewr.behvr.api.ProcessEventApi") && ($.message="Null message generated for request:*")}
```

I didn't realize that I could add wildcards within the value itself. Once I used this expression, I was able to get the correct set of logs to match.